# Type 'EmbeddedInstance<XProps>' is not assignable to type 'EmbeddedInstance<{}>'

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with my TypeScript code, and don't know how fix It. The code itself works fine, but VSCode show problems:

```
Type 'EmbeddedInstance<XProps>' is not assignable to type 'EmbeddedInstance<{}>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'XProps'.
'XProps' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.
```

There is my Types part

```
export interface EmbeddedInstance<X = {}> {
    tag: string,
    (props: X),
    render(element: string | HTMLElement): Promise<unknown>,
}

export type XProps =
  ///...
  ///other code
  ///...
  | {}
```

There is my logic part

```
export class ScaledPreview<Options, XProps> extends Component<Props<Options, XProps>, State> {
    instance?: EmbeddedInstance

    ///...
    ///other code
    ///...

    componentDidMount () {
        //Here VS Code gives an error 
        this.instance = EmbeddableUtils.initComponent(component, options)
    }

    async componentDidUpdate (prevProps: Props<Options, XProps>, prevState: State) {

        try {
            await this.instance({
                setHeight: 100,
                onLivePreviewInit: 200,
                ...(props || {}),
            }).render(element)

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    ///...
    ///other code
    ///...
}
```

IMG linkg

> http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2021/05/03/0017/3494/1133990/90/2d7ee3c05e.png

Comment: What does *initComponent* look like?  What are the variables component and options?

Comment: @DanielGimenez, http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2021/05/03/0017/3494/1133990/90/3b74146385.png

Both variables is object

Comment: I don't understand how this.instance is typeof *EmbeddedInstance<XProps>*.  Is your example accurate?